# Unable to run the code effectively If condition is not functioning effectively

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

I have an array of month & year and i have a start month and year. What i want to do is to filter out the month and year which matched to the start month and year.
But for some reason my if loop is not filtering month & year

Code Snippet:

```
for (let a of data) {      
if (start_date_data[0].month && start_date_data[0].year !== a.month && a.year) {}
```

where am i going wrong ? please help

Image for reference data
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAFwb.png]

Answer (score 2):

It should be :-

```
for (let a of data) {      
if (start_date_data[0].month !== a.month && start_date_data[0].year !== a.year) {}
```

Comment: I did interchange, the output what i'm getting is that all the all the months from that year are eliminated 
For instance 
start month_year is [10, 2020] and the array has [10 , 2020 , 11 , 2020 , 1 , 2021 ] it's displaying 1,2021 instead of [11 , 2020 , 1 , 2021]

Comment: unless you give whole code which you have in if condition, we can't help you with that.

Comment: this.authService.getmonthsandyear(this.id).subscribe(data => {      
      this.authService.startdate(this.id).subscribe(start_date_data => {      
        for (let a of data) { 
    if ( a.month !== start_date_data[0].month && a.year !== start_date_data[0].year)  {                      
            this.authService.getmonthwiseyear(a.month, a.year, this.id).subscribe(data => {  }